# mboost/glmboost doesn't return proper result and na.action doesn't handle my NA issue

Tags: r, na

I have a problem with `glmboost` from the `mboost` package. After fitting the model (99 obs, 311 variables) it only returns an intercept with value 0 and no other variables:

```
glmboost(myformula, data = train, family = Gaussian(), na.action = na.pass, control = boost_control(nu = 0.1, mstop = 2000,  trace = TRUE))

 Generalized Linear Models Fitted via Gradient Boosting

Call:
glmboost.formula(formula = myformula, data = train, na.action = na.pass, control = boost_control(nu = 0.1, mstop = 2000, trace = TRUE), family = Gaussian())


 Squared Error (Regression) 

Loss function: (y - f)^2 


Number of boosting iterations: mstop = 2000 
Step size:  0.1 
Offset:  6.536275 

Coefficients: 
(Intercept) 
      0 
attr(,"offset")
[1] 6.536275
```

I choose `trace = TRUE` to print the risk:

```
[    1] ................................................................................................................................................... -- risk: 0 
[  150] ................................................................................................................................................... -- risk: 0 
[  299] ................................................................................................................................................... -- risk: 0
```

and so on for all 2000 steps.

The risk already starts with 0. I do not have an intuition for that. Do you?

I played with the formula and recognized that with some variables it is working properly, with some it is'nt.

One "problem variable" I found contains only NAs. I thought that `na.action = na.pass` could handle that problem. Am I wrong or could there be another issue causing that problem?

I also played with `nu`,`mstop`, and `family` but it didn't help me to solve the problem. I read a lot of mboost paper but couldn't find an issue like mine.

In another attempt I removed all variables with more than 52% NAs in the data before fitting the `glmboost`. Then everything worked fine.

To sum up:

1. What could be a reason that I don't get coefficients/start with risk 0?
2. Why cause variables with a lot of NAs problem and why doesn't `na.action` handle that?

Comment: Why aren't you offering results of `str(train)`? I'm not a user of that package, but I would have assumed the right na.action would be `na.omit`. I would guess that the "risk" is being returned in the offset term. You don't provide the formula so that's speculation on my part.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't offer `str(train)` results. But there are some thousends of variables, but all numeric. Due to the fact that all varibles have some missing variables `na.omit` would remove my complete data set. My formula is in this style `y ~ x1 + x2 + ... + x5000`. What do you exactly mean by "risk is being returned in the offse termt"? My risk already starts with zero in the fist iteration. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please remove your variable with `NA`s before fitting the model. This should solve your problem. In general any regression model will fail if you have a variable that contains only missing values. That is in general a user problem which needs to be solved in advance of fitting the model.

We are currently investigating the behaviour of `mboost` when `NA`s are present ([issue 12](https://github.com/hofnerb/mboost/issues/12)) and will take your problem into consideration as well.

For the future please try to post such issues directly on the [github](https://github.com/hofnerb/mboost) development page. This will allow us (i.e., the authors/maintainers of `mboost`) to directly chime in.